# How safe and compiler-independent is this C++ code?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, static, virtual-functions

I have created a bit of code that is strange to me, but seems to do what I want. However, I am not sure of its platform independence or how safe it is, or if there is a much easier way to do what I want.

I was reading on the Curiously Recurring Template Program ([on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)), and there was sample code for a class counter that lets each derived class keep track of how many instances have been created by inheriting from a base with that functionality.

I had been looking for ways to have derived classes reference to a common object (by pointer) without having to add a static variable and define a virtual function for each new class I create. (I was planing on creating quite a few derived classes.) But, the derived classes, because they were created with templates, were considered different from the base so they could not be implicitly converted to a base pointer.

Dynamic_cast and static_cast didn't work, so I tried reinterpret_cast, for fun, to see what behavior that had. It ended up showing the static variable from the base class, which isn't what I wanted, but it reminded me of a previous experience I had with statics and virtual functions (long story). I wrote a virtual function in the base class, and the virtual function reported the correct variable for the derived classes, polymorphic-ally.

It works, at least according to codepad.org, but I'm still not sure of its platform consistency or the safety of reinterpret_cast in this case. Can someone with more experience than I clarify exactly why this works?

Here is my code. It looks like the Wikipedia sample code because that's what it was originally.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class counter
{
    public:
    static int separateObject;
    virtual void printStatic(){
    cout << this->separateObject << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T> int counter<T>::separateObject( 0 );

class X : public counter<X>
{
    // ...
};

class Y : public counter<Y>
{
    // ...
};

typedef counter<void*>* voidcounter;
int main(){
    X* counterX = new X;
    Y* counterY = new Y;
    counterX->separateObject = 9001;
    counterY->separateObject = 42;
    cout << "Object Xs value is: " << counterX->separateObject << endl;
    cout << "Object Ys value is: " << counterY->separateObject << endl;
    voidcounter polycount = reinterpret_cast<voidcounter>(counterX);
    polycount->printStatic();
    polycount = reinterpret_cast<voidcounter>(counterY);
    polycount->printStatic();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `struct interface { virtual void printStatic() = 0; }; template<typename T> struct counter : interface { static int separateObject; void printStatic() override { cout << separateObject << endl; } };`?

Comment: @BillLynch Sorry about the external link, I'm new to StackOverFlow.

Comment: @dyp That's one way to do it, but I wanted to avoid re-defining a function in every single class I derived from "counter" in the case of my code and "interface" in the case of your example.

Comment: @gajbooks: You didn't read his code close enough, he has _two_ interfaces.  One dynamic (regular normal inheritance), and one CRTP that inherits from the dynamic.  Your classes inherit from the CRTP interface, which gets them both parts.

Comment: @MooingDuck But wouldn't that only ever reference the "separateObject" from the "counter" class?

Comment: @gajbooks: There's two `counter` classes, one with the `X` parameter, and one with the `Y` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had been looking for ways to have derived classes reference to a common object

Then don't use CRTP.  CRTP is for when you need all of the base types to NOT be common (which is what allows each type to have it's own counter).  That's 100% exactly what it's for.  If you want a shared common base, use a normal virtual base class.  You can't use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` because they have no base in common.  What you're doing with `reinterpret_cast` is incredibly unsafe, as it is undefined behavior.

```
class shared_counter_base {
    virtual ~shared_counter_base(){}
    virtual void printStatic()=0;
};

template <typename T>
class counter : shared_counter_base 
{
    public:
    static int separateObject;
    virtual void printStatic() {
    cout << this->separateObject << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T> int counter<T>::separateObject( 0 );

class X : public counter<X>
{
    // ...
};

class Y : public counter<Y>
{
    // ...
};

int main(){
    X* counterX = new X;
    Y* counterY = new Y;
    counterX->separateObject = 9001;
    counterY->separateObject = 42;
    cout << "Object Xs value is: " << counterX->separateObject << endl;
    cout << "Object Ys value is: " << counterY->separateObject << endl;
    shared_counter_base  polycount = counterX;
    polycount->printStatic();
    polycount = counterY;
    polycount->printStatic();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If anything, I would abandon the approach because of `reinterpret_cast` being unsafe. I was unsure if compilers generated different code for each derived class, despite no usage of template-dependent members.

Comment: @gajbooks: They certainly do, that's the entire reason CTRP exists.